Java 8: How to filter the map from a list of list Ids and generate new List using Streams
Firstly This is not a duplicate question.
I have list of List<Integer> and Map of Integer Ids and Employee Object as below:
List<List<Integer>> ids=new ArrayList<new ArrayList<Integer>>();
ids.add(Arrays.asList(1,2));
ids.add(Arrays.asList(2,3));

Map<Integer, Employee> employeesByEmployeeId=new HashMap();
employeesByEmployeeId.put(1,new Employee("Test"));
employeesByEmployeeId.put(2,new Employee("Test1"));
employeesByEmployeeId.put(3,new Employee("Test2"));
employeesByEmployeeId.put(4,new Employee("Test3"));

Now I have to fetch list of Employee whose Ids are present in ids list.
Result
[Employee("Test"),Employee("Test1"),Employee("Test2")]

Solution which is not complete--
List<List<EmployeDTO>> employeeDto=data.getEmployee().stream().map(EmployeeDto::getSubEmployee).toList();
Set<Set<Integer>> ids=employeeDto.stream().map(employee -> employee.stream().map(EmployeeDto::getIds).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
            

Note: this is a dummy data

Have you tried anything? How would you do it without streams?

How would Empoyee get an ID? All you're doing is passing a String to its ctor

You've edited your code (not that it would compile though) but you still haven't shown us how Employee gets an ID in the first place

@g00se the id is the map key. It's not part of the Employee class.

@g00se post updated.

What's incomplete about your solution? Why is it incomplete?

how to covert Set<Set> to Set

Maybe List<Employee> byId = ids.stream().flatMap(List::stream).map(id ->employeesByEmployeeId.get(id)).toList();

@g00se you will need a distinctin there somewhere or you will end up with duplicates.

If that's a problem, the easy solution is to collect a Set instead. A bigger problem is that you might get nulls, but that's easy to filter out

Stream the Map's entrySet, filter using a Predicate, map to get the Entry's value, then collect:
List<Employee> filteredList = employeesByEmployeeId.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> ids.contains(e.getKey()))
  .map(e -> e.getValue())   //or Entry::getValue
  .toList();

EDIT:
Since you changed your requirements around, first convert your List<List<Integer>> to a List<Integer>like this:
List<List<Integer>> idLists= new ArrayList<>();
idLists.add(List.of(1,2));
idLists.add(List.of(2,3));

List<Integer> ids = idLists.stream()
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .distinct()
  .toList();

And then use the code above.

I have edited the question, actually it bit complex. can you please recheck and help me on this.

If I understood your problem correctly, it seems that you could do something like this:
List<Integer> allIds = ids.stream().flatMap(List::stream).toList();

List<Integer> myValues = employeesByEmployeeId.keySet().stream().filter(allIds::contains).toList();

Not sure why you need this complexity, though.
PS: My solution is based on changing the "List<List> " in your code to "ArrayList<ArrayList> "

You are missing a mapafter filter, otherwise you get a List<Map.Entry>.

Could it be that there was some copy/paste mistake? I seem to be getting a List of Integers when pasting it in IntelliJ

someMap.keySet().stream().filter(...).toList() does not return a List<Integer>.

Weird. I am not getting any errors. But you may customize the code according to your needs

allIds::contains is also incorrect as it passes the Entry to contains, not the Entry's key.

I think I found the problem. My solution is based on changing the "List<List> " in your code to "ArrayList<ArrayList> ".

That does not change any of the issues I mentioned. And I still doubt that your code compiles.

I just compiled it and it ran without any problems. Perhaps you should give it a try yourself before you mention any issues with it. As previously mentioned, it is based on a modification of your code that uses ArrayLists instead of Lists in the beginning.

Can you post your code on ideone then? I am curious how that would work.

Now I realize that your thread is for Java 8. It works fine with Java 19 & 21 though.

Neither the java version nor ArrayList vs List have anything to do with this code not working

What do you see here, my brother in Christ? https://postimg.cc/BXRscLtF

Ah, you stream the keySet. For what reason?
